# Посоветуйте, исходники каких открытых проектов стоит изучить новичку (С++)

Tags: c++, opensource

Знаете ли вы открытые проекты, которые действительно стоит изучить новичку, чтобы на примере увидеть как писать реальный код. (естественно, не все подряд, а реально стоящие и ценные с точки зрения корректности и грамотности программирования)

Comment: В разделе геймдева Doom 3 https://github.com/id-Software/DOOM-3

Comment: Библиотка общего назначения boost https://www.boost.org/

Comment: Базы данных libsoci https://github.com/SOCI/soci

Comment: DOOM-3 новичку я бы не советовал, кстати :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот отличный пример https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp.

Написан на более-менее современном языке, показано как организовывать CI, тестирование, coverage, генерить документацию, пользоваться различными способами сборки, организовывать исходный код проекта в целом.